# Ontario condo light installation

Tags: electrical, wiring, light

My friend's condo has a junction box installed in the ceiling, but no light.

1. Can we legally install a light here? [Ontario's ESA page](https://www.esasafe.com/consumers/home-buying-selling-and-renovating/do-it-yourself/#need-a-permit) states that installing a light requires a permit, but does that include installing a light onto an existing junction box?
2. If we remove the cover, we see the following wires:

   - green (connected as though it's ground)
   - white
   - orange
   - yellow
   - blue
   - brown

We were expecting a green, white and black (or red) wire. The green white and orange wire appear to emerge from the same point on the side of the box. Am I correct in assuming that the orange wire is live?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo looking up into the box?

Comment: Please post a picture of the wiring in the box.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the pictures, but it's hard to see how the wires are connected (including the disconnected yellow ones). Would you itemize which ones are connected where?

Comment: Don't assume anything when dealing with electricity.

Comment: Don't assume all those wires *are there to serve your purpose of installing a light*.  Most are not, and if you mess with them, you will break other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crossbar and the cut yellow wire suggest that a lamp was previously installed there.

It is OK to install a lamp yourself but to comply with code you must call a licensed electrician to inspect your work. I can see from the picture that the ground (green bundle) is being used as a neutral connection (white wires) and the end of the yellow wire is just floating, so even if you do nothing you will need an electrician to make it safe.